# Why Next.js meta tags are not found by bots/crawlers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, axios

I am using Next.js with Typescript, and MongoDB to fetch data. I am having problems rendering the page because the crawler cannot detect the meta tags.

For example, Bing Search Engine says Title and Meta description tags are missing, even though I can see them. Maybe it's because of `axios` and `useState`. Can anyone guide me on what should be the solution?

Inspector of my website:

[image]

Bing URL Inspection:

[image]

[pid].tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Navbar from '@/sections/Navbar';
import BlogBody from '@/sections/BlogBody';
import Footer from '@/sections/Footer';
import axios from 'axios';
import { IBlog } from '@/schema/blogSchema';
import Error from '@/components/Error';
import Loading from '@/components/Loading';

const Blog = () => {
  const _router = useRouter();
  const { pid } = _router.query;
  const [currentDoc, setCurrentDoc] = useState<IBlog | undefined>();
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pid !== undefined) {
      const apiAddr = `/api/queries?action=searchexact&target=${pid}`;
      axios.get(apiAddr)
        .then((res) => {
          setCurrentDoc(res.data.data[0]);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setIsError(true);
        })
    }
  }, [pid])

  return (
    <>
      {
        currentDoc && (
          <Head>
            <title>{currentDoc.title} - Wayne Blogs</title>
            <meta name="description" content={currentDoc.desc} />
            <meta name="author" content={currentDoc.author} />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.svg" type="image/x-icon" />
          </Head>
        )
      }

      <Navbar />
      <main>
        {
          isError ? (
            <Error text="There was a problem fetching the document, please refresh the page" />
          ) : (
            currentDoc ? (
              <BlogBody blogInfo={currentDoc} />
            ) : (
              <Loading />
            )
          )
        }

        <Footer />
      </main>
    </>
  )
}


export default Blog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are fetching data on the client inside `useEffect`, and only then setting the `Head`. The result is that the HTML file that Next.js send (you can view it in the source tab of devtools) won't contain the `Head` data.

It's recommended to render your `Head` on the server. And for that, you could use a server-side [data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching) function, like [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props). In your case, it would be similar to:

```js
const Blog = ({ currentDoc }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{currentDoc.title} - Wayne Blogs</title>
        <meta name="description" content={currentDoc.desc} />
        <meta name="author" content={currentDoc.author} />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.svg" type="image/x-icon" />
      </Head>
      <Navbar />
      <main>
        <BlogBody blogInfo={currentDoc} />
        <Footer />
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const res = await axios.get(`/api/queries?action=searchexact&target=${context.query.pid}`);

  return {
    props: { currentDoc: res.data.data[0] },
  };
};

export default Blog;
```

Notice that I'm not handling possible errors. I let you do that.

Comment: I was losing my braincells, i couldn't understand why i am getting this error.. i searched the internet (maybe i didnt know what to search for.. because i even read about getServerSide) i just didn't understand. i am a hobbyist programmer (not a qualified one) just doing my best to learn NextJS. Thank you again for solving it means a lot

Comment: I see. It actually happens to everyone to miss something for quite a long time sometimes. And again, it's my pleasure :)

Comment: i am still facing the same problem, the loading is fixed (your solution worked) but crawlers can't seem to find the content and meta of page (if you wanna test my live link please let me know)

Comment: After doing as a said, ensure you are not getting the result of the previous tests (sometimes this can be the case, either because your server is returning a previously cached version, or the bot is reading from a cache).

Comment: Thank you for this awesome support brother, okay let me see what i can do first. i will contact you once i feel doomed once again